# How to pick image from Gallery only

Tags: android

I want to pick the photo from Gallery but from below codes its showing Gallery with SD card external applications like ex Astro Manager. I want it should show me only the Gallery not other third party application or related to that stuff etc.

Dummy code which currently list all the application which can browse like Astro Manager etc.

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*"); 
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),10);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct one, but you need little help from me. Just looks at link it will help you to handle Gallery  [Link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/pick-image-from-galary-android-app/)

For your task, you can add this sample code

```
Intent i = new Intent(
Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

Comment: link only answer is not good idea on SO now that's why I edited your answer with some code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
private static final int PICTURE_GALLERY = 1;
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, PICTURE_GALLERY);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your app is supporting a sdk version JELLY_BEAN_MR2. It is better to open the intent like,

```
Intent intent;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("image/*");
    } else {
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("image/*");
    }
checkAndStartActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);


private void checkAndStartActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {
    //Open only if any intent can be handled from some component
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager())!=null) {
        startActivityForResult(createChooser(intent, ""), requestCode);
    }else{
    //show error to user
    }
}
```